# Detect click on link in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift3

I am not able to detect a tap on a link inside a `UIWebView`. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but there are nothing logged when navigating by clicking links in my `UIWebView`.

This is my `WebViewController`

```
import UIKit

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class WebsiteViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var backButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var webview: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

let user = UserDefaults.standard

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if webview.canGoBack {
        webview.goBack()

        return true
    }

    return false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

    let url = URL(string: "http://" + user.string(forKey: "site")!)

    webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))

    //webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    print("test log a click")
    print(navigationType)
    return true
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I can't see it.

Comment: Check if webview.delegate is set to self.

Comment: Wow @bunty, worked on this for hours and you really helped me go further. THANKS A LOT!! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: When in doubt check your IBOutlets, actions, and delegates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if webview.delegate is set to self.